# Call Wallpaper Set Service

Tags: android

I need to call from my activity a simple window to choose for what set wallpaper as it shown on screenshot below:

[image]

I dont find anything useful when search.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this do the job but you can try to broadcast this intent: [android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER)

> Activity Action: Show settings for choosing wallpaper

Comment: Thanks, but SET_WALLPAPER not work as need. SET_WALLPAPER just call installed app for view image, but I need as show on screen